# Equality in Expression Trees doesn't use the correct operator overload

Tags: c#, expression-trees, roslyn

I got a something odd issue with expression trees and operator overloading (in particular with `==` and `!=` operators).

I'm using the MemberwiseComparer from one of Marc Gravell's answers, more or less the one

```
public static class MemberComparer
{
    public static bool Equal<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        return EqualComparerCache<T>.Compare(x, y);
    }

    static class EqualComparerCache<T>
    {
        internal static readonly Func<T, T, bool> Compare = (a, b) => true;

        static EqualComparerCache()
        {
            var members = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Cast<MemberInfo>()
                .Concat(typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredFields.Where(p => !p.IsStatic && p.IsPublic).Cast<MemberInfo>());
            var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y");

            Expression body = null;
            foreach (var member in members)
            {
                Expression memberEqual;
                if (member is FieldInfo)
                {
                    memberEqual = Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Field(x, (FieldInfo)member),
                        Expression.Field(y, (FieldInfo)member));
                }
                else if (member is PropertyInfo)
                {
                    memberEqual = Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(x, (PropertyInfo)member),
                        Expression.Property(y, (PropertyInfo)member));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException(member.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Name);
                }

                body = body == null ? memberEqual : Expression.AndAlso(body, memberEqual);
            }

            if (body != null)
            {
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, bool>>(body, x, y);
                Compare = lambda.Compile();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a base class `ValueObject<T>` that serves as base class for value objects.

```
public class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<T> where T : ValueObject<T>
{
    public virtual bool Equals(T other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return MemberComparer.Equal<T>((T)this, other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as T);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return MemberComparer.GetHashCode((T)this);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        // If both are null, or both are same instance, return true.
        if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        {
            return true;
        }

        // If one is null, but not both, return false.
        if (((object)left == null) || ((object)right == null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ValueObject<T> left, ValueObject<T> right)
    {
        return !(left == right);
    }
}
```

In general this works fine for classes which implement `IEquatable<T>` or scalar types and/or strings. However, when the class contains properties which are classes that implement `ValueObject<T>`, the comparison fails.

```
public class Test : ValueObject<Test>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Test2 : ValueObject<Test2>
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

When comparing `Test` with `Test` it works fine.

```
var test1 = new Test { Value = "TestValue"; }
var test2 = new Test { Value = "TestValue"; }

Assert.True(test1==test2); // true
Assert.Equals(test1, test2); // true
```

But when comparing `Test2` it fails:

```
var nestedTest1 = new Test2 { Test = new Test { Value = "TestValue"; } }
var nestedTest2 = new Test2 { Test = new Test { Value = "TestValue"; } }

Assert.True(nestedTest1==nestedTest2 ); // false
Assert.Equals(nestedTest1, nestedTest2 ); // false

// Second Test with referenced Test object
var test = new Test { Value = "TestValue"; }
var nestedTest1 = new Test2 { Test = test }
var nestedTest2 = new Test2 { Test = test }

Assert.True(nestedTest1==nestedTest2 ); // true
Assert.Equals(nestedTest1, nestedTest2 ); // true
```

The `==` operator override is called for the `Test2` class, but not for `Test` class. When `nestedTest1` and `nestedTest2` reference the same `Test` object, it works. So the `==` overload is not called when the expression is built and compiled.

I couldn't find a reason why it would ignore it. Is this some change to Roslyn no one noticed or is there something wrong with the expression tree generation?

Of course I could rewrite the Expression Tree generation to call `.Equals` method instead, but this would add more complexity (and additional null checks). But the actual question is, why doesn't the compiled Expression Tree use the `==` overload and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up implementing a method which searches for the `op_Equality` operator override method and pass it to `Expression.Equal` as the 4th parameter.

```
MethodInfo equalsOperator = FindMethod(memberType, "op_Equality", false);

equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(left, memberInfo),
    Expression.Property(right, memberInfo),
    false,
    equalsOperator);

... 
private static MethodInfo FindMethod(Type type, string methodName, bool throwIfNotFound = true)
{
    TypeInfo typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();

    // TODO: Improve to search methods with a specific signature and parameters
    while (typeInfo != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methodInfo = typeInfo.GetDeclaredMethods(methodName);
        if (methodInfo.Any())
            return methodInfo.First();

        typeInfo = typeInfo.BaseType?.GetTypeInfo();
    }

    if (!throwIfNotFound)
        return null;

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Type '{type.GetTypeInfo().FullName}' has no '{methodName}' method.");
}
```

In my simple scenario it's sufficient (for now) to use the first `op_Equality` found there should be not more than one in the `ValueObject<T>` class and I made sure the `MemberComparer.Equal<T>((T)this, other)` is only called, when both objects are of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

After digging down little, here is the issue. Operator `==` is not defined in class `Test` but it is defined in `ValueType<T>`.

If you call,

```
// this is used by Expression.Equal (it does not search for base type)

var m = typeof(Test).GetMethod("op_Equality", 
            BindingFlags.Static 
            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

//m is null because op_Equality is not declared on "Test"

var m = typeof(ValueObject<>).GetMethod("op_Equality", 
            BindingFlags.Static 
            | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

// m is not null
```

This is the reason Expression does not use operator equality method.

It seems Roslyn does use equality operator when it is compiled, but Expression compiler is not part of Roslyn, and this seems bug in the line http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/BinaryExpression.cs,b3df2869d7601af4 where it does not search for method in base classes.

Comment: At first I thought that too, but I don't get it why `Assert.True(test1==test2);` did work, but the same expression (`memberEqual = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(x, (PropertyInfo)member),Expression.Property(y, (PropertyInfo)member));`) via expression trees doesn't. In the above case, the == operator is called when I set breakpoints in it.

Comment: Because operator for String is defined in string class. Also there is difference between c# compiler and expression compiler. == operator is called by c# compiler. May be it is bug.